# How to make a list of articles in a navbar

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to do something that may look dumb to you, but that is a real challenge to me. I have to make a list of 10 articles in a navbar that has a width of 20vw, and each one has to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufCoZ.png)

I have tried many things but I don't know if there is a "proper way" to do that

```
<nav class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="articlepic">
                <img src="https://i.neilrichter.com/g8qp8.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="article_description">
                <h6>Le récap' des bons plans du moment, semaine 43</h6>
                <p>Il y a 7 heures</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here's my css:

```
.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 20%;
    width: 20vw;
    height: auto;
}

.side_articles {
    display: flex;
    margin: 10px;
}

.sidebar img{
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
}
```

It looks like ugly like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drpmn.png)

Do you have recommendations / tips / examples on how to do it?

Comment: Start with lists. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Comment: I'll replace the `<div class="side_articles">` by `<li>` items then, I'll change this

Comment: The reason the question has been marked down is because you've not shown the attempts to style it how you'd like - please research into how to correctly output list elements in HTML and then how to style them with CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired (and taken) from Bootstrap Media block styles:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/

Adjust padding, colors and other styles as needed.

```css
.article {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.article img {
    border-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1rem!important;
    max-width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.article-body {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.article-heading {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sidebar">
    <div class="side_articles">
        <div class="article">
            <img src="https://i.neilrichter.com/g8qp8.png" alt="">
            <div class="article-body">
                <h3 class="article-heading">Le récap' des bons plans du moment, semaine 43</h3>
                <p>Il y a 7 heures</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you ! It turns out that picture size impacts a lot in the layout. I'll have to find the correct size to make it work as I want.

Comment: @NeilRichter You're right! And make all images one size, usually around 100px wide for small images. Bootstrap uses 64px wide images in their demo

Comment: Well, the sidebar I am trying to is for a tablet size (min 641px). And the sidebar is "only" 20vw, which actually is not that much, and my problem is whether the picture is too small, whether it's too big and there's no room for description ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this pen and then change your code accordingly.
https://codepen.io/aalokindreams/pen/ZXQGVB

```
.side_articles {
    display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
flex-flow: row wrap;
-webkit-flex: 4 1 60%;
flex: 4 1 60%;
padding: 0px;
background: #fff;
border: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you get the first example from? Examine their code and try to dissect it. That said, you'll need [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) for the icons. You'll probably also need to include a font from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/). Also, just setting the width for your image won't cut it with such a tight spacing, you should probably enforce a strict pixel-perfect size (use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to target different screen sizes) - usually such a sidebar is a strict layout, so letting your image stretch as it wants is not an option. That said, experiment by yourself and come back whenever you find a more specific question. Stack Overflow isn't really for such general guidance.

Comment: I just need the layout for the moment. 
So I don't think I have any troubles with Google fonts nor Font Awesome.
The goal of this project is mainly to use media queries so don't worry they are used. 
I guess I'll have to adjust the size of my image if I want something that looks a little bit like the example given

Comment: Do you use any framework at all? Have a look at [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), or any other grid-based framework, it'll speed up your CSS development dramatically.

Comment: I'm really into my first weeks of Web Developments, so I don't know all the tools, but I checked the rules and the only think I can't do is jQuery. But I'll check Bootstrap, another answer advised me to do that.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for Bootstrap's grid system, it allows you to split your "article" into two pieces, image on the left and text on the right, without any nasty hacks